# XSL FO - Different page numbering in footer for each element

Tags: xml, xslt, xsl-fo, apache-fop

Sample XML:

```
<ResultSet>
  <WC>
   <Id>1</Id>
  </WC>
  <WC>
   <Id>2</Id>
  </WC>
  <WC>
   <Id>3</Id>
  </WC>
</ResultSet>
```

I'm trying to start page numbering from 1 and count only the amount of pages for each WC element.

For example, if the first WC element have 2 pages, the first page will 1/2 and the second 2/2 and for the second WC element which have 3 page, it will start the count from 1, and first page will be 1/3 and so on.

Is that possible to achieve?

I'm using Apache FOP.

Any help will be appreciated.

EDIT:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:fo="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Format" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

    <xsl:output method="html" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"/>

        <xsl:template match="/">

            <fo:root>
                <fo:layout-master-set>
                    <fo:simple-page-master master-name="A4" page-height="279.5mm" page-width="216mm"> 
                        <fo:region-body region-name="xsl-region-body" margin="62mm 10.4mm 16mm 10.4mm" />
                        <fo:region-after region-name="xsl-region-after" extent="16mm"/>
                        <fo:region-start region-name="xsl-region-start" extent="10mm"/>
                    </fo:simple-page-master>
                </fo:layout-master-set>

                <xsl:for-each select="ResultSet">
                    <fo:page-sequence master-reference="A4" >

                        <fo:static-content flow-name="xsl-region-after" >
                            <fo:block font-size="9pt" font-weight="normal" font-family="Helvetica" margin="0mm 10.4mm 0mm 0mm"></fo:block>
                            <fo:block>Page <fo:page-number/> of <fo:page-number-citation ref-id="last-page" /></fo:block>
                        </fo:static-content>

                        <fo:static-content flow-name="xsl-region-start">
                            <fo:block-container border="1px solid black" height="256mm" width="195mm" margin-top="6.5mm" margin-left="10mm">
                                <fo:block>&#160;</fo:block>
                            </fo:block-container>
                        </fo:static-content>

                        <fo:flow flow-name="xsl-region-body">
                            <fo:block-container font-size="9pt" font-weight="normal" font-family="Helvetica">
                                <fo:block id="last-page"> </fo:block>
                            </fo:block-container>
                        </fo:flow>
                    </fo:page-sequence>
                </xsl:for-each>
            </fo:root>
        </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: You want to restart page numbering for each `<WC>`? Can you provide us the stylesheet you already set up for the moment?

Comment: Yes. I provided the basic stylesheet that I'm using when I'm building templates. But I have no idea how to set up page layout that will fit my question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically you need to start a new `<page-sequence>` for each `WC` element, this will allow you to restart the page numbering from 1.

Then you need a unique identifier for each number citation, to retrieve the page number of each section. I am assuming that the `Id` tag can be used for that.

This should do the job (please note that FOP is quite buggy regarding the retrieval of the last page number in some cases - a commercial product like Antenna House Formatter works much better):

```
<xsl:template match="/">
    <fo:root>
        <fo:layout-master-set>
            <fo:simple-page-master master-name="A4" page-height="279.5mm" page-width="216mm"> 
                <fo:region-body region-name="xsl-region-body" margin="16mm 10.4mm 16mm 10.4mm" />
                <fo:region-after region-name="xsl-region-after" extent="16mm"/>
                <fo:region-start region-name="xsl-region-start" extent="10mm"/>
            </fo:simple-page-master>
        </fo:layout-master-set>
        <xsl:apply-templates />
    </fo:root>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="WC">
    <xsl:variable name="id.wc">id_<xsl:value-of select="normalize-space(Id/text())" /></xsl:variable>
    <fo:page-sequence master-reference="A4" initial-page-number="1">

        <fo:static-content flow-name="xsl-region-after">
            <fo:block font-size="9pt" font-weight="normal" font-family="Helvetica"
                margin="0mm 10.4mm 0mm 0mm">
                <fo:block>Page <fo:page-number/> of <fo:page-number-citation ref-id="{$id.wc}"
                /></fo:block>
            </fo:block>
        </fo:static-content>

        <fo:static-content flow-name="xsl-region-start">
            <fo:block-container border="1px solid black" height="256mm" width="195mm"
                margin-top="6.5mm" margin-left="10mm">
                <fo:block>&#160;</fo:block>
            </fo:block-container>
        </fo:static-content>

        <fo:flow flow-name="xsl-region-body">
            <fo:block-container font-size="9pt" font-weight="normal" font-family="Helvetica">
                <!-- Process the content of the WC here... -->
                <xsl:apply-templates />
                <!-- This empty block is used to retrieve the last page number of the current section -->
                <fo:block id="{$id.wc}" />
            </fo:block-container>
        </fo:flow>
    </fo:page-sequence>

</xsl:template>
```

Comment: First of all, thank you for your answer. It seems to do the trick. But for some reason it creates me a blank page after each page (except the last one). What could be the reason?

Comment: Never mind, found an answer, added force-page-count="no-force" in page-sequence. Thank you!